# Power BI : "MySQL: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset."

Tags: mysql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Mysql is running in my localhost. I already verified connectivity using a mysql client like DBeaver.

In Power BI I am trying to connect with server name as "127.0.0.1:3306" and database name as 'oc3038'. In the second screen for credentials, I choose Database tab and entered the mysql root credentials.

When Connect button is clicked it gives a warning like

"We were unable to connect to the data source using an encrypted connection. To access this datasource using an unencrypted connection, click 0K."

On clicking ok, below error message appears and it fails to connect

```
We encountered an error while trying to connect
Details: "MySQL: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset."
```

I already tried with localhost instead of 127.0.0.1, server name without port number and also tried increasing the timeout up to 10 minutes. Even turning off the firewall did not make any difference